when i install node js npm did not working
PS C:\Users\hp> npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.20.4
Could not determine Node.js install directory

why this problem occur to me
EDIT:
After updating to node 20, I still experience the same errors.
PS C:\Users\hp> node -v
v20.15.1
PS C:\Users\hp> npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.15.1
Could not determine Node.js install directory
PS C:\Users\hp> 


is npm -v node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143 throw err; ^ what YOU typed? - never mind - poor formatting fixed

How did you install node? Why did you install node version 18 now when version 20 is the current release?

i tried all the versions but not working

Looks like your Npm installation is broken somehow. Completely uninstall Node.js, make sure there are no traces of it (e.g. C:\Program Files\nodejs doesn't exist at all anymore), then reinstall it.

Had the same issue. There was a path entry (and also in .bashrc) to C:\Users\%username%\.nvm\versions\node\v22.3.0\bin. Removed the link and uninstalled node. After reinstall all worked again. It installed version 20.17.0 (LTS)

1. Update Environment Variables:
The error message mentions "Could not determine Node.js install directory." This could mean your system environment variables aren't set correctly. Here's how to fix it:
Search for "environment variables" in your Windows search bar.
Edit your system environment variables (not user variables).
Find the variable named "Path" and edit it.
Make sure the path to your Node.js installation directory (e.g., "C:\Program Files\nodejs") is included in the list of paths, separated by semicolons (;).
Save the changes and restart your terminal for the update to take effect.
Or
2- Reinstall Node.js

Please check the path of node in environment.
Ensure that the installation directories (C:\Program Files\nodejs in your case) have the correct permissions set and that your system PATH includes the path to npm (C:\Program Files\nodejs).
please use npm install -g npm@latest if you are using outdated version.

PS C:\Users\hp> node -v
v20.15.1
PS C:\Users\hp> npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.15.1
Could not determine Node.js install directory
PS C:\Users\hp> 

new version also i did not get npm access

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
